# PCManFM Alt+Up keyboard shortcut no longer works

Tags: debian, pcmanfm

After Upgrading my Debian Stable to the Buster version, the alt+up keyboard shortcut (doing `cd ..`) doesn't work any more. Both Alt+Left (Back) and Alt+Right (Forward) work fine.

I'm using Awesome WM and I haven't set Alt+Up as a customized key binding.

(PCManFM version 1.3.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> (while waiting for the next release); see the Manjaro forum posts [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pcmanfm-alt-up-not-working/90351/3) and [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pcmanfm-alt-up-not-working/90351/6) where it's said:

> Some further investigation/troubleshooting:
>   I applied the patch submitted by user Michael Weghorn in the bug report and the key bindings were working after that.
>   The patch has been merged to the source code, so hopefully the issue will be resolved in the next release.

Comment: Despite the downvotes (why?) I can confirm that in my Debian 10.2+LXDE system ALT UP doesn't work but BACKSPACE does.

Comment: Same here for me (funtoo / i3), this is very frustrating.  Hopefully this will be fixed soon.